# StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler does not use applicationTaskExecutor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have `Spring Data REST` custom controller that returns `ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>`

In my application.yaml file, I have defined a custom task executor to be used for the  StreamingResponseBody.

```
spring:
  task:
    execution:
      pool:
        max-size: 16
        queue-capacity: 100
```

However, mvc is still using the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`, instead of the one defined above.

```
An Executor is required to handle java.util.concurrent.Callable return values.
Please, configure a TaskExecutor in the MVC config under "async support".
The SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor currently in use is not suitable under load.
```

After a little debugging, I found out that the `StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler` does not set the `applicationTaskExecutor` on the `WebAsyncTask` type i.e. `StreamingResponseBodyTask` and as a result the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` is used.

```java
Callable<Void> callable = new StreamingResponseBodyTask(outputMessage.getBody(), streamingBody);
WebAsyncUtils.getAsyncManager(webRequest).startCallableProcessing(callable, mavContainer);
```

The `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` is picking up the `applicationTaskExecutor` and setting it correctly, when I debugged this method in `WebMvcAutoConfiguration`

```java
@Override
public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
    if (this.beanFactory.containsBean(TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.APPLICATION_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME)) {
        Object taskExecutor = this.beanFactory
            .getBean(TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.APPLICATION_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME);
        if (taskExecutor instanceof AsyncTaskExecutor) {
            configurer.setTaskExecutor(((AsyncTaskExecutor) taskExecutor));
        }
    }
    Duration timeout = this.mvcProperties.getAsync().getRequestTimeout();
    if (timeout != null) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(timeout.toMillis());
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything? How can I apply the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for a `StreamingResponseBody`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spring-data-rest` Custom Repositories (`@RepositoryRestResource` or `@BasePathAwareController`) Ignore `AsyncSupportConfigurer`
see `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration#repositoryExporterHandlerAdapter` [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java).
But `spring-webmvc` applies `AsyncSupportConfigurer` see `WebMvcConfigurationSupport#requestMappingHandlerAdapter` [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java)

```
    AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer = getAsyncSupportConfigurer();
    if (configurer.getTaskExecutor() != null) {
        adapter.setTaskExecutor(configurer.getTaskExecutor());
    }
    if (configurer.getTimeout() != null) {
        adapter.setAsyncRequestTimeout(configurer.getTimeout());
    }
    adapter.setCallableInterceptors(configurer.getCallableInterceptors());
    adapter.setDeferredResultInterceptors(configurer.getDeferredResultInterceptors());
```

If it's possible, use a simple `@RestController` or `@Controller`,
If not, you can create an issue [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues) to add support for that